# Help with naming molecule

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I am trying to name the molecule pictured below. I thought it would be 5-bromo-4-isopropyl-2-methylhex-2-ene, but googling that name does not show any results, which makes me think it is not right. Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

[image: 5-bromo-4-isopropyl-2-methylhex-2-ene]

Comment: This is how I would be happy to name it, but there are IUPAC rules that you need to look up about systematic naming. You could look at ChemSpider and try the molecular formula; you will find very many compounds, however.

Comment: The name is really not the correct one, from two major reasons - substituents given by prefix, like methyl and bromo, or bromoethyl, have the same priority (there's no priority), and because of rules [P-45.2.1](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=P-45.2.1), [P-45.2.2](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=P-45.2.2)

Answer (score 3):

The suggested name 5-bromo-4-isopropyl-2-methylhex-2-ene is not wrong; however, it is not the preferred name according to current IUPAC recommendations.

Since the compound has a double bond but no principal characteristic group that would be expressed as a suffix, it is clear that the parent structure is a **2-methylhex-2-ene.** However, there is a choice between two different principal chains, which lead to different names:

- 5-bromo-2-methyl-4-(propan-2-yl)hex-2-ene and
- 4-(1-bromoethyl)-2,5-dimethylhex-2-ene

Both possible chains have two additional (but different) substituent groups in the same positions; therefore, the usual nomenclature criteria related to number and location of substituent groups do not help. Finally alphabetical order is used to identify the preferred name as **4-(1-bromoethyl)-2,5-dimethylhex-2-ene.**